# Touchpal keyboard keeps disabling itself on HTC Desire

Tags: htc-desire

I have an HTC Desire (2.2) which I have installed TouchPal Keyboard. The problem is though it seems to keep disabling itself and reverting to the default keyboard layout.

I then have to go through the rigmarole of setting it back to TouchPal as the preferred input method.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure the application is installed internally, and not on to your sd card.

from http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/07/apps-on-sd-card-details.html:

> **When not to install on SD card?**
>
> The advantage of installing on SD card is easy to understand: contention for storage space is reduced. There are costs, the most obvious being that your app is disabled when the SD card is either removed or in USB Mass Storage mode; this includes running Services, not just interactive Activities. Aside from this, device removal disables an application’s Widgets, Input methods, Account Managers, Device administrators, Live wallpapers, and Live folders, and may require explicit user action to re-enable them.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following troubleshooting options:-

1. Uninstall and then re install TouchPal. Be sure to restart your
   phone after you uninstalled it.
2. Install any other IME and see if the problem is repeated there. This
   will make sure that the problem is with TouchPal or with your
   device.

Comment: I have TouchPal keyboard installed in 2 phones of mine - Galaxy SL and Galaxy S. It seems to work pretty fine there.

Answer (score 1):

Do you use any kind of app-killer?  My thought is that somehow the TouchPal application is being killed, not necessarily manually, but somehow automatically through the app-killer. If not that, then you can maybe use an app-killer or another app in the reverse sense - that is, somehow prevent the app from being killed.

The reason I say this is that I use the Go Keyboard and sometimes I would accidentally kill it via a task killer, and next time I use the keyboard it would go to Swype.

Answer (score -1):

I would re install Android to the newest version. Either do it yourself, or go to a phone shop and pay 10$ or so for them to reinstall your phone.

If this solves your problem, it was a cheap fix. If it didn't work, you can go back to the phone shop where you bought the phone and make them fix it in guarantee.

If you want to try to download and install an awesome rom for your phone, you should read this: http://www.cyanogenmod.com/devices